# Child prop not updating, even though the parent does

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a pretty weird situation where a change in a child component's `prop` is not triggering a re-render.

Here is my setup. In the parent I have:

```
        <child :problemProp="proplemPropValue""></child>
```

In the child I have defined the prop:

```
{
    name: "Child",
    props: {
    problemProp: {
        type: [File], //yes it is a file 
        required: true
    }
}
```

and then I try to render it  (still in the child component)

```
<template>
  <div id="dropzone-preview" class="file-row">
    {{problemProp}} <--This should just show the prop as a JSON string-->
  </div>
</template>
```

This is rendered correctly initially. But `problemProp` has a property `upload.progress`, and when I change it in the parent (I can confirm that it does change on the parent)  it does NOT change in the child.

If I now add a second prop, `dummyProp` to the child:

```
   {
    name: "Child",
    props: {
    problemProp: {
        type: [File], //yes it is a file 
        required: true
    },
    dummyProp: {
        type: Number
    }
}
```

Now, when `dummyProp` changes, `propblemProp` also changes. What is going on here? Why does the change in `dummyProp` force a re-render but a change in `propblemProp` does not?

Comment: How is `progress` added tp `proplemPropValue`?

Comment: @Bert I listen to Dropzonejs events and update it through a Vuex store. `progress` is not really "added" to  proplemPropValue. When `proplemPropValue` is initialized, it is initialized with `progress` on it. Does that answer the question?

Comment: How is it updated? The behavior you are describing sounds like the code is falling into a change detection caveat (the value is changed, but Vue doesn't know it has).

Comment: So the child component is actually one of many generated by a `v-for` on an array. Everytime one of the items in the array changes I update the array using `arr.splice(indexOfItem,1, newValue)`. This change is reflected in both the Vuex store and the parent, but not the child.

Comment: The arr.splice happens at the source of truth - the store

Comment: Can't really help without code. Ideally a working example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @Bert, I've reproduced the problem in a bin [here](https://jsbin.com/cudibikinu/edit?html,output). I have also added some commented code that, when uncommented causes the changes to be detected (specifically, adding dummyProp to the mix)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154615/discussion-between-sello-mkantjwa-and-bert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of the problem appears to be that when you add a File object to the array, Vue *fails* to convert it into an observed value. This is because [Vue ignores browser API objects](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data):

> The object must be plain: native objects such as browser API objects
> and prototype properties are ignored.

That being the case, any changes to that object will not be reflected in the Vue automatically (as you would typically expect) because Vue doesn't know they changed. That is also why it appears to work when you update `dummyProp`, because changes to that property *are* observed and trigger a re-render.

So, what to do. I've been able to get your bin to work by making a small change to the `addedFile` method.

```
addedfile(file){
  console.log(file);
  self.problemPropValues.push(Object.assign({}, file));
},
```

First, you don't need (or want) to use `$data`, just reference the property directly. Second, by making a copy using `Object.assign`, Vue properly observes the object and updates are now reflected in the child. It *may* be the case that you will need to use a deep copy method instead of `Object.assign` at some point, depending on your use case, but for now this appears to be working.

[Here is the code](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/PJPRoY?editors=1010) I ended up with getting the bin to work (converted to codepen because I find working with codepen easier).

Comment: Thanks for the analysis @Bert. I went through the vue.js observer source code and found this that an observer is setup for a value if this condition holds: `(Array.isArray(value) || isPlainObject(value))`, where `isPlainObject` is defined as `Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) === '[object Object]'`. Turns out for a file `Object.prototype.toString.call(file)==='[object File]'` and thus the condition fails. Just gonna open an issue to find out why files are being ignored. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa I had no idea that's how they were detecting plain objects. I've seen/used code where the object being observed was the results of a javascript constructor (or class) and it worked fine. Interesting that File fell into this crack where it *acts* like an object but toString renders it differently. Vue does state they prefer plain objects for data in the docs somewhere.

Comment: Yep. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data

From the docs: >The object must be plain: native objects such as browser API objects and prototype properties are ignored. A rule of thumb is that data should just be data - it is not recommended to observe objects with its own stateful behavior.

Comment: @SelloMkantjwa Thanks for that link :) I knew it was somewhere. I updated the answer with your additional findings.